# Using LINQ to find the latest item in a collection which in turn has a collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of products, each product has a collection of Warehouses and then inside the collection of warehouses there is a collection of locations.

I need to return all products which I am doing fine but I need to return the locationWithStock which is a member of the collection of locations inside the collection of warehouses.

I have this so far **but it's wrong, because StockDate is not a member of Warehouse but of its collection.** I need only the Latest (most recent date) of the StockDateS, hence I need to look inside each StockDate which there is 1 in each memeber Location and only return the latest.

```
        var items = from j in products
              let locationWithStock =
                            j.Warehouses.OrderByDescending
                         (a => a.StockDate).FirstOrDefault()
                        select new 
                        {
                            Name = j.Name,
                            Warehouse = locationWithStock.Name
                        }
```

### Edit

I will try and explain a bit more. Here is the hierarchy:

Products.

Each product has multiple warehouses.

Each warehouse has multiple locations.

I need to return all products and each product must contain the location name.

What is the criteria to find the location when there are multiple warehouses and multiple locations?

I must search in each warehouse and in turn each location, and return OUT OF ALL OF THEM the latest location (ONLY 1) which I detect using the StockDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Products**

    each **product.Warehouses** multiple warehouses

        each **Warehouse.Locations** multiple locations in each Warehouse.

I assumed Whatever **return all products which i am doing fine**(in your question) translates to some condition on prodduct state, so I represented that condition with `where p.Doing == "Fine"` where clause in below code which you could modify appropriately.

```
var stocks =
           from p in products
           from w in p.Warehouses
           from l in w.locations
           group l by l.Date into g
           let maxDate = g.Max(l1 => l1.Date)
           select new { Product=p.Name, Location= g.Where(l2 => l2.Date == maxDate) };
```

Comment: Sorry maybe i didn't explain it right.. Doing Fine... means i am currently returning all products without an issue.... nothing to do with code...

Comment: yes you are correct 
 

Products
each product.Warehouses multiple warehouses
each Warehouse.Locations multiple locations in each Warehouse.

Comment: locationWithStock  needs to contain the Latest Date from Locations but rememeber that each product contains multiple warehouses and each warehouse contains multiple locations..  The date is a member of the location.

Comment: I didnt get what exactly is the filtering criteria from your question.

Comment: ok i have updated the question... hope its a bit better now..its quite difficult to explain :-)

Comment: Based on your update on question, updated the answer, it should work for you now.